# Problem with negative cash flow in the Numpy_financial.irr () function

Tags: python, numpy

The `Numpy_financial.irr()` function returns the value of the internal rate of return from the cash flows reported as an argument.

However, when the cash flow is negative, (this can occur due to costs not foreseen in the project, for example, which may exceed the expected revenue), the function does not work, when this happens, the function output returns: `nan`.

```
import numpy_financial

cf = -10
invest = 1000

irr = numpy_financial.irr([-invest,cf,cf,cf,cf,cf,cf,cf,cf])
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I assume it's because it can't find a solution to the NPV equation?

Comment: For an irr calculation to have real solutions there must be at least one negative and at least one positive cash flow.  Your example only has negative flows.  -1000 and 8 times -10.